# Make a button pop up an information title before it performs its action

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mapkit

A perfect example of the function I want performed is when you open Google maps and click on a location and before giving you the details about where the location is, it simply pops up with a title of what you clicked. I have an image that is a map with 16 different location button pins. When a button is clicked I want a pop up with what the person clicked on (just the title), then an option to continue to the details of the location (which is on a seperate view controller).

As of now I have 16 buttons (pins) on top of an image (map) that when clicked on take you to a new view controller with the details of the location. For this I simply control dragged a button to a new view controller. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want, don't control drag from the button to the new viewController. Instead create an @IBAction method that handles your required functionality and then, if the user chooses to click through to the details of the location, call the segue programmatically.

Comment: How can I go about doing this? If I create an action that pops up a label when the button is clicked how do i then make it so if you click on the label it takes you to a new view controller? I have this function which creates a label as of now:  @IBAction func btnpressed1(_ sender: Any) {
        let title = (sender as AnyObject).title(for: .normal)!
        scottsLabel.text = "this is a test \(title) button"

Comment: via above comment.. @Magnas

Comment: Control drag from the yellow circle above your initial viewController (the one with your button and label) to the destination viewController and make a segue. Give it an identifier. This segue can now be initiated from your code with the performSegue method. You can either put a button in your label or attach a tapGestureRecognizer to the label to initiate it.